# How can I add Arabic typing in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I want to add Arabic typing in VB.Net. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It already supports it; it's all unicode under the hood now.  If your users have an arabic keyboard layout the standard controls and inputs should accept arabic text.  You do need to make sure to use a system that supports unicode for any persistence you use (database, config files, etc), but the vb.net layer should already work.